# How does dalvikvm understand the starting point of android application

Tags: dalvik, dex

I can successfully run a simple java program in dalvikvm by converting the java class into dex file. But when I try to run android application by converting its class files into dex, it says static main(String args[]) not found.

Android application does not contain static main() method.

So where does dalvikvm start executing an android application or how does it find the static main() method in android application???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android determines your app's entry point based on the `AndroidManifest.xml` shipped with your app. Specifically, Android determines which intent was sent to the app (to cause it to launch), and will instantiate the appropriate Activity and call its `onCreate` method. This creation process is overseen by a wrapper process called `app_process`, which calls into dalvik directly and sets up the app execution environment.

Dalvik itself behaves like a normal Java JVM in most regards; therefore, running a `jar` or `dex` with Dalvik will still expect a `main` method, as with normal Java.

Comment: Dalvik is not a JVM -- it does not execute Java bytecode.

Comment: @fadden: "behaves like a normal JVM" != "is a normal JVM"

Comment: @fadden: sorry, didn't see that, I'm using the mobile web version.

Comment: I can not find the executable for zygote. Which executable in AOSP runs to start the zygote process?